# Two way tables and the Chi square Test in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on a R-project for school. I have a question concerning the project. I have to print a two way tables, and each cell of my table should contain the result of a Chi square test.

For example :

[image: My two-ways table]

For example, the 0.7 is the result of the chi square test between Orange and Apple.

I know how to do the chi square test between two variables :

```r
chisq.test(c(data_frame$Apple, data_frame$Orange))
```

Then I tried to print the two-way tables :

```r
list <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Grappe")
for (element in list) {
   for (element2 in list) {
      chisq.test(c(data_frame$element, data_frame$element2))
   }
}
```

But it's not working, I have an infinite loop.

Can someone help me with this problem ? I am new to R
Also, sorry for my English

Comment: Use `data_frame[[element]]` and the same with `element2`. You are also not assigning the result of the test. And I've seen much worse english.

Comment: Hello Rui Barradas, you want me to replace data_frame$element by data_frame[element]$element ?

Comment: No!!! Replace `data_frame$element` by what I've written, `data_frame[[element]]`. The difference is that `element` is a character string that contains the name of a df column, but is *not* a column itself.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I don't have any errors or warnings but there is nothing on the screen, is that normal ?

Comment: That is because `for` loops return `NULL` and you are not assigning the result of the tests. Wait, I will post an answer.

Comment: Why isn't your sample table symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seing `data_frame` it's not possible to know if the following code does what you want, but here it goes.
First of all, I've changed the name of the vector to `mylist` since `list` is an R function.

```
mylist <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Grappe")

pval <- lapply(mylist, function(x){
    lapply(mylist, function(y){
        if(x != y) {
            chisq.test(data_frame[[x]], data_frame[[y]])$p.value
        }
    })
})
pval
```

This will only produce the p-values, if you want the full output of `chisq.test` you would use

```
result <- lapply(mylist, function(x){
    lapply(mylist, function(y){
        if(x != y) {
            chisq.test(data_frame[[x]], data_frame[[y]])
        }
    })
})
```

This produces a nested list of lists, each of the elements of the nested lists is an object of class `htest`, the ones returned by hypothesis testing in R.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Grappe")
while (element in list) {
   while (element2 in list) {
      chisq.test(c(data_frame$element, data_frame$element2))
   }
}
```

Comment: We can't do element in list with the while loop